# How to fix cors error faced even with cors setup on the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have configured my code in this manner on my express backend and have the cors library installed.

I am however getting this error:

> Access to fetch at 'mybackend.com' from origin 'domain1.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I solve this?

My backend and frontend code are as below respectively

```
const allowedDomains = [
    'domain 1',
    'domain 2',
    ];
```

```
app.use(cors(
     {
     origin: function (origin, callback) {
     if (allowedDomains.indexOf(origin) != -1) {
     callback(null, true);
     } else {
     callback(new Error(`Access has been blocked `));
     }
     },
     credentials: true,
     }
    ));
```

```
await fetch(`mybackend.com' ,{
     method:'GET',
     headers: new Headers({
     'Content-Type':'application/json',
     'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`,
     }),
     body:null,
     })
```

Answer (score -1):

As per my limited understanding of Fetch API and CORS, I think you have to add `mode: 'cors'` as well as the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'mybackend.com'`. After doing that, your `await fetch(...)` block would look something like this.

```
fetch(URL, {
  mode: 'cors',
  method:'GET',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  body:null,
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => { ... });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually found a fix , i had used the cors below my route paths and had not noticed it so i just copied the cors part and pasted it above the paths , it is not necessary to add the mode but i think it is good practice and i will start using that